# JavaScript Date ISO8601

Tags: javascript, date

What is the best way to get a Javascript Date object from a string like the following one:

```
2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00 ?
```

I have trouble with the time zone part (obviously).

Comment: ISO8601 dates were introduced with ECMAScript v5. Older browsers will not support it.

Comment: when you use new Date(SomeISODateString), how to prevent it from converting to local date time...?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
alert(myDate);
```

Comment: The ISO8601 format has just been standardized in [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15), in browsers with ES3 implementations it wont work, since there was no a *default format* described in that version of the specification.

Comment: @CMS, good to know. Seemed too easy :) @Luc, check out **Eli's** answer if you are supporting browsers implementing ES3.

Comment: @jason-mccreary, hmmm.... I was trying to split every bit of the string and building a new date and you come with this solution... Well, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @jason-mccreary, your solution is fine, I do not depend upon a browser, this is node.js stuff.

Comment: It's worth noting that ES5 does NOT support `+0200` or `+02` but only `+02:00` for UTC-offset. This is not in line with ISO 8601 which allows `±[hh]:[mm]`, `±[hh][mm]`, or `±[hh]`.

Answer (score 7):

IE 8 and below, and older versions of the other browsers do not implement the ISO Date format. A problem is that some of the browsers do return a date, instead of NaN, just not the correct one.

You can write your own method,  if you want to support them. The time zone is the tricky bit.

This example will run once and set a Date.fromISO method- if the native method is supported it will use it.

```
(function(){
var D= new Date('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
if(isNaN(D) || D.getUTCMonth()!== 5 || D.getUTCDate()!== 2 ||
D.getUTCHours()!== 7 || D.getUTCMinutes()!== 34){
    Date.fromISO= function(s){
        var day, tz,
        rx=/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/,
        p= rx.exec(s) || [];
        if(p[1]){
            day= p[1].split(/\D/);
            for(var i= 0, L= day.length; i<L; i++){
                day[i]= parseInt(day[i], 10) || 0;
            }
            day[1]-= 1;
            day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
            if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
            if(p[5]){
                tz= (parseInt(p[5], 10)*60);
                if(p[6]) tz+= parseInt(p[6], 10);
                if(p[4]== '+') tz*= -1;
                if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
            }
            return day;
        }
        return NaN;
    }
    // remove test:
    alert('ISO Date Not correctly implemented');
}
else{
    Date.fromISO= function(s){
        return new Date(s);
    }
    // remove test:
    alert('ISO Date implemented');
}
})()


// remove test
var D=Date.fromISO('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
alert(D.toUTCString())
```

Answer (score 5):

If your string is an ISO8601 string, you can just pass it into the Date constructor and get a Date object back out:

```
var date = new Date('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
```

According to http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/09/21/date-from-iso-8601-string/ though, this might have issues in IE and other platforms. It recommends you do something like this for compatibility:

```
function dateFromISO8601(isostr) {
    var parts = isostr.match(/\d+/g);
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] – 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
}

var myDate = dateFromISO8601("2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00");
console.log(myDate);
```

Comment: is the timezone taken into account ? It returns Sep 20 2010 when you use Jun 02 2011.