# Working with Parse.com dates

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform

I have dates stored using Parse.com backend.  I retrieve them using JSON.stringify.  Everything is working fantastic except for dates.  I need to convert them to JavaScript dates.  I understand that Parse.com stores dates in ISO 8601 format preceded by characters as in this example:

{"__type":"Date","iso":"2013-05-07T00:00:00.000Z"}

Could sure use some help on trying to convert above to standard JavaScript date. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The iso8601 isn't an issue: see [JavaScript Date ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228302/javascript-date-iso8601)

As for getting the item out, don't use JSON.stringify, just access the part you need:

```
var d = {"__type":"Date","iso":"2013-05-07T00:00:00.000Z"};
d = new Date(d.iso);
```

Comment: OMG !!!!   it works!  I've been working on this all day.  Tested it.  Works great.  Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

For those who dont know how to get the date and the time from an input (Works in chrome, opera and safari)
HTML code

```
<input type="date" id="thedate">
<input type="time" id="thetime">
```

Javascript code

```
var a = document.getElementById("thedate").value;
var b = document.getElementById("thetime").value;


x = a + 'T' + b + '+02:00'; //the +02:00 is because i live in Greece and we are +02:00 GMT! Choose your own.
var d = {"__type":"Date","iso":x};
d = new Date(d.iso);
```